# Regex is allowing white spaces and complete blank spaces

Tags: java, regex

Let me make it clear. I have to validate 2 phone numbers. they are my requirements. Not specific to any country. it can be left blank. meaning, its not mandatory. But it should not be

1. Filled with white spaces -- i should throw error
2. should not contain spaces in between Like 12 123

I am using the pattern ^[-+()0-9]{1,20}$. case 1 is failing with this regex. How can i fix it?

Comment: you could use .trim() method

Comment: Some examples for valid match would be great.

Comment: Your regular expression allows at minimum one character and at maximum 20 characters of the set `-`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `0`, ..., `9`. Where exactly do you see the allowance of any whitespace character?

Comment: Hi All.,. I mean.. when its completely filled with space.. its failing.. Like 12 123 is being trapped in the pattern... but if the input is all whitespaces.. its failing to validate

Comment: Try to use `\S` ,it will select only **NonWhiteSpace** characters.

Comment: @sandeep I tried to explain that your regular expression _does not match_ a string if it contains any whitespace at any position. So the string `12 123` is not valid according to that regular expression.

Comment: Hi @Seelenvirtuose .. Correct.. 12 123 will not work .. what if If i want to filter a field which is filled completely with whitespaces? the trim method mentioned above is not working :(

Comment: you've tried this [^\s] ?

Comment: @sandeep Your question is very unclear. It does not get clearer by simply adding comments that each is only a part of your problem description. Please edit your question, and first add a proper explanation of your requirements, then add examples of what you want to match and what you do not want to match, and last add the regular expressions which you already tried.

Comment: @sandeep: Are you trying to match **Indian mobile phone number** ?

Comment: I am trying the [^\\s] .. Now.. as suggested  above

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Let me make it clear. I have to validate 2 phone numbers. they are my requirements. Not specific to any country. it can be left blank. meaning, its not mandatory. But it should not be

Filled with white spaces -- i should throw error
should not contain spaces in between Like 12 123
I am using the pattern ^[-+()0-9]{1,20}$. case 1 is failing with this regex. How can i fix it?

Comment: If it can be left blank, then you need to change the `{1,20}` to a `{0,20}`.

Comment: Also, technically your pattern says that `(((((((((` and `------` and `(-)(-)(-)` are valid phone numbers, among others.

Comment: I Agree.. They should be allowed as per my requirement.(I know its wrong...) can you tell me how can I reject blank spaces ?

Comment: You keep saying "reject blank spaces", but as others have pointed out, your pattern does not allow blank spaces. So I think you've got a logic issue elsewhere. Maybe how you've implemented this regex in an `if` block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHONE_NUM.replaceAll("[^0-9]","")` to eliminate all the non-numbers.

Then, if your result's `.length()` is more than 20, you have too many digits. If it's 0 (meaning empty), you were not given a phone number.

If you can handle whitespace properly, it will reduce user frustration.